# Need to do first commit using bitbucket rest API

Tags: java, bitbucket, spring-rest, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am using bitbucket rest api for creating new private repository & create new branch. Both api's are working fine.

**POST https://{bitbucket url}/rest/api/1.0/users/{username}/repos** -> create new repository

**POST https://{bitbucket url}/rest/api/1.0/users/{username}/repos/{repo name}/branches** -> create new branch

But i need to do that in a single call, Say i am created one new repository and i am not able to create branch. Because it is empty repository. So we need to do the first commit in MASTER branch, then only it allow me to create a new branch.

I need to do that first commit using bitbucket rest api. But i am not able to find that API.
Could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bitbucket API for adding new commits :

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src#post

From docs:

> This endpoint is used to create new commits in the repository by uploading files.

Comment: For me bitbucket version 2.0 is not working.
https://bitbucket.myorg.dev/2.0/repositories/<username>/<repo_slug>/. 
But version 1.0 is working(https://{bitbucket.myorg.dev}/rest/api/1.0/users/{username}/repos)

Comment: Is there any API related to version 1.0 for adding new commit

Comment: Getting 404 Not found

Comment: Bitbucket server has an entirely [different REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.9.0/bitbucket-rest.html) from Bitbucket cloud. ([Reference](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Does-the-rest-api-2-0-exist-for-server/qaq-p/881631))